# Remove existing lines from the previous iteration in a for-loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, seaborn

I inserted the following code into a for-loop:

```
for code in list_code:
     .....
    sns.lineplot(original['Date'], original['Open'])
    sns.lineplot(df_forecast['Date'], df_forecast['Open'])
    plt.savefig(f"output_{code}.png")
```

The first iteration, there were only 2 lines (correct). 
[image] 
In the second iteration, the 2 lines from the first iteration were also added to the image,
so that I now had 4 lines instead of only 2 lines.
[image]

After the last iterations, there were so many lines (I only need 2 lines per image).
How can I run the for-loop without the lines from the previous iterations being included?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just `plt.cla()` after saving the figure.

This will clear your current axes